# How do I post form data on a single page homepage

Tags: php, html, forms, post

```
<form name="makeup" action="index.php" method="post">
                <select id="skin_shade">
                    <option value="skin_shade_1">Dark</option>
                    <option value="skin_shade_2">Light</option>
                </select></br>
                Acne:<input type="checkbox" value="acne"/></br>
                Oil:<input type="checkbox" value="oily"/></br>
                Straight Hair:<input type="checkbox" value="straight"/></br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

<?php
echo $_POST['skin_shade']?>;
```

I get no output after I hit submit except for the form resetting.

Comment: If your problem solved then mark john's answer "as answer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `<select id="skin_shade">` to `<select name="skin_shade">` ?

Comment: In general, `id` is used to identify an element using JavaScript or style using CSS... `name` is used for `POST` or `GET` parameters in PHP